# Meaning of effective mass in a spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

In real life we don't have ideal spring so when doing experiments we need to take in our calculation the mass of the spring it self (the effective mass) wich made me doubt about the physical meaning of the effective mass in a spring and why we should consider it while doing measures?

Comment: I have to admit that I do not understand your question. Punctuations and shorter sentences would probably help. Maybe you could also state what is your problem with the standard explaination: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(spring–mass_system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to understand this by thinking about a statics problem, not simple harmonic motion.

Suppose you have a spring fixed at the top and with a mass hanging from the bottom. The spring will extend because of the weight of the mass, and because of the weight of the spring itself.

Suppose the spring is length $l$ and the bottom moves down a distance $x$. Because the spring stretches evenly along its length, the *average* movement of the material in the spring is $x/2$. If the mass of the spring is $m$ and the added mass is $M$, the change in potential energy is $mgx/2 + Mgx = (M + m/2)gx$.

To simplify the math, it is convenient to say that the "effective mass" of the spring is $m/2$ and its mass is all at the bottom of the spring.

For simple harmonic motion, you can use the same idea but the details are different. Because the kinetic energy depends on the *square* of the velocity, it turns out that the effective mass at the end of the spring is $m/3$, not $m/2$.

As these two examples show, the effective mass is not just a property of the spring itself but of the whole system and how the system moves. For example in the statics case, if the top of the spring was *not* fixed, the effective mass would be different.

Note that the usual value of $m/3$ for the effective mass in dynamics is only an approximation, and assumes that $m$ is much smaller than $M$. To get an "accurate" model, you would have to consider the "exact" motion of the spring, which is *not* an uniform extension along its length. But that is beyond the scope of a first course in dynamics and simple harmonic motion.